# You cannot load dependent objects for more than 1000 resources. Use a filter to restrict your query

Tags: csom, project-online

I am trying to do something that I thought would be really simple - get a single assignment of a single enterprise resource.

My code is this:

```
var resource = ctx.EnterpriseResources.GetByGuid(resourceId);
ctx.Load(resource);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var assignment = resource.Assignments.GetByGuid(assignmentId);
ctx.Load(assignment);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Too many resources: 2643. You cannot load dependent objects for 
more than 1000 resources. Use a filter to restrict your query.
```

The error is also described here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4fab5f62-5955-4257-af0f-a5e1fa58dca7/error-reading-project-custom-fields-via-csom-too-many-projects?forum=projectonline

But I do not understand why we get  this error. We get a single resource and we try to get a single assignment for it - why does it complain about affecting more than 1000 (2643) resources?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you get the error on the first or the second block?

Comment: You don't understand it because it's an unintuitive, poorly designed api.  A properly designed api shouldn't require chunking or multi-second response for simple queries and operations.  Of course if you wanted a billion records in one HTTP call that's an issue, but plenty of cloud apis deal with these kinds of queries routinely and with high performance every day. I'm working through the same issues now.  If I end up with a solution that's easy to share I'll post it back here.